# consulta en mysql sobre ingresos y egresos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema cuando ejecuto este código:

```
SELECT sum(TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE) ,TB_INGRESOS.ID_CUENTA 
from TB_INGRESOS 
GROUP by ID_CUENTA;
```

me sale el reporte agrupado de manera correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora cuando agrego a lado los egresos agrupados por el id_cuenta usado este codigo:

```
SELECT sum(TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE) ,sum(TB_EGRESOS.IMPORTE) 
from TB_INGRESOS , TB_EGRESOS 
WHERE TB_INGRESOS.ID_CUENTA = TB_EGRESOS.ID_CUENTA GROUP by TB_INGRESOS.ID_CUENTA;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya no suma igual, al usar inner join obtengo el mismo resultado:

```
SELECT TB_CUENTAS.ID_CUENTA, case WHEN TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE> 0 then sum(TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE)else 0 END as ingresos, sum(TB_EGRESOS.IMPORTE) as egresos 
FROM TB_CUENTAS 
JOIN TB_EGRESOS on TB_EGRESOS.ID_CUENTA=TB_CUENTAS.ID_CUENTA 
JOIN TB_INGRESOS on TB_INGRESOS.ID_CUENTA=TB_CUENTAS.ID_CUENTA 
GROUP by TB_CUENTAS.ID_CUENTA;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito mostrar el los ingresos y egresos agrupados por el id_cuenta
he probado varias formas, y no encuentro la solución.
revise sin agruparlos por el id_cuenta y el problema es que al no encontrar datos repite el ingreso o egreso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo la cuenta 3 en la realidad solo tiene un ingreso y 3 egresos, pero la consulta repite los ingresos para igualar el numero de egresos.

Comment: Pon el resultado real q esperas para q se te entienda mejor

Comment: ¿No sera esto lo que quieres?  `SELECT sum(TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE) ,sum(TB_EGRESOS.IMPORTE), TB_INGRESOS.ID_CUENTA`  Es decir, tienes que mostrar el id_cuenta tambien en los resultados para realizar bien la agrupacion, o eso creo... Prueba y nos comentas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema aparente de las sumas erróneas, es que los `JOIN` están actuando sobre las filas de la tabla y no sobre la filas agrupadas. Una forma posible de resolverlo es unir primero todas las filas, las de egresos e ingresos y sobre estas aplicar el `group by`

```
SELECT T.ID_CUENTA,
       SUM(T.Ingresos)  As Ingresos,
       SUM(T.Egresos)   As Egresos
       FROM (
        SELECT  ID_CUENTA,
            TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE  As Ingresos,
            0                    As Egresos
            FROM TB_INGRESOS 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  ID_CUENTA,
            0                    As Ingresos, 
            TB_INGRESOS.IMPORTE  As Egresos
            FROM TB_EGRESOS
       ) T
       GROUP BY T.ID_CUENTA
```

Nota: Otra posibilidad y tal vez más clara y explicativa, es agupar egresos e ingresos y luego unir horizontalmente por la cuenta, mediante el `full outer join`, el problema es que `mysql` no cuenta con esta cláusula, la respuesta que te dí, básicamente esta emulando el `full outer join`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha servido el código para realizar las operaciones de manera correcta.